How to make the link to the Group Input Node and the Group Output Node from other Nodes?
Blender 4.1. I can't figure out how to connect the NodeGroupInput's Geometry output to the Bounding Box node's input. When I list the inputs and outputs of the Bounding Box node, and other nodes, I can see them in the log. However, when I try to list the inputs and outputs of the NodeGroupInput and NodeGroupOutput nodes, it seems that they don't have any. Since these nodes start without any by default, I assume this is the issue. I tried creating the attributes, but it's not working...
class OBJECT_OT_EnlargerMachine(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.enlarger_machine"
    bl_label = "Enlarger Machine"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # Create a new geometry node group
        node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type='GeometryNodeTree', name='TempNodeTree')
        nodes = node_tree.nodes
        links = node_tree.links

        # Clear default nodes
        for node in nodes:
            nodes.remove(node)

        # Add nodes
        input_node = nodes.new(type='NodeGroupInput')
        bbox_node = nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeBoundBox')
        join_node = nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeJoinGeometry')
        output_node = nodes.new(type='NodeGroupOutput')

        # Set node locations for better organization
        input_node.location = (0, 0)
        bbox_node.location = (200, 0)
        join_node.location = (400, 0)
        output_node.location = (600, 0)

        # Add sockets to the input and output nodes
        input_node.outputs.new('NodeSocketGeometry', 'Geometry')
        output_node.inputs.new('NodeSocketGeometry', 'Geometry')

        # Link nodes
        links.new(input_node.outputs['Geometry'], bbox_node.inputs['Geometry'])#Doesn't work because NodeGroupInput doesn't have any Geometry output
        links.new(bbox_node.outputs['Bounding Box'], join_node.inputs['Geometry'])#WORK
        links.new(join_node.outputs['Geometry'], output_node.inputs['Geometry'])#Doesn't work because NodeGroupOutput doesn't have any Geometry input
        # Add the node group as a modifier to the active object
        active_obj = context.view_layer.objects.active
        if active_obj:
            modifier = active_obj.modifiers.new(name="EnlargerMachine", type='NODES')
            modifier.node_group = node_tree
        else:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "No active object selected.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'FINISHED'}

How to make the link to the Group Input Node and the Group Output Node since they don't have Inputs nor Outputs?


Look at my answer there: blf module: How to draw text in the center? - I link specifically to the 3rd revision, because in the next I removed the code. More specifically, look at the get_text_centering_offset function. BTW, chatGPT generated code doesn't really add value to the question, IMHO it degrades its quality significantly.


Thanks for your answer.
Denigrate? Low quality? Please, come on XD. Thanks, though.


I don't even read the code when I recognize it's AI-generated, I wish it was clearly marked as such so I wouldn't waste time figuring this. The reason being, AI generated code often doesn't represent the actual problem, you could as well google for your problem and copy-paste the first code snippet you found - it's a hit and miss, could be relevant or not.

Dude, chill. The code was "perfect" enough; so don’t act like that. The only exception was the problem that I clearly established in the title, body, and I even provided code. You immediately recognized the problem and directed me to the right answer. I just don’t understand why that diminished the question in any way, shape, or form. Anyway...thanks, though.

It diminished the question, because it took me some time to parse it and recognize it as chatGPT, the time I could spend elsewhere, simple as that. I am chill.
